# FCM Notifications: SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get a Xamarin.Android app to test out using of FCM for different types of communications, and I've been able to get everything set up but when i attempt to get a registration token for my Visual Studio Emulator - Android (Marshmallow), i'm getting this error..

> java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
>   act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms
>   (has extras) } without permission
>   com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE 04-12 11:43:44.679
>   E/FirebaseInstanceId( 1793):

This is my Android.manifest  - full contents out of obj\debug

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="net.fqtrs.xamtest" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
  <!--suppress UsesMinSdkAttributes-->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
  <!-- This app has permission to register with GCM and receive message -->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <!-- Required to wakeup the device and deliver messages -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <permission android:name="net.fqtrs.xamtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="net.fqtrs.xamtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:label="FCMNotifications" android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="net.fqtrs.xamtest" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="FCMNotifications" android:name="md50b8cb7a267d8690e7668352ad20476c5.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="md50b8cb7a267d8690e7668352ad20476c5.MyFirebaseIIDService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="md50b8cb7a267d8690e7668352ad20476c5.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="net.fqtrs.xamtest.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.net.fqtrs.xamtest" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:authorities="net.fqtrs.xamtest.firebaseinitprovider" android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" />
    <!-- FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true" -->
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:exported="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with it. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What does your final `AndroidManifest.xml` inside your `obj/Debug/Android` contain?